# Error While generating pascal's triangle in plSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, buffer-overflow, pascals-triangle

well I'm pretty new to plSQL and I can't seem to figure out some errors I'm getting while trying to generate a pascal's triangle

Here's the code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    N NUMBER;
    I NUMBER;
    J NUMBER;
    K NUMBER;
    L NUMBER;
    T NUMBER;
    S NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTER THE LIMIT');
    N:=&N; 
    I:=0;
    T:=N-2;
    S:=0;
    L:=0;
    WHILE (I<N) LOOP
        J:=0;
        WHILE (J<T) LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ');
            J:=J+1;
        END LOOP;
        K:=0;
        WHILE (K<=S) LOOP
            IF (K<=I) THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(K+1);
                L:=K;
            ELSE
                L:=L-1;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(L+1);
            END IF;
            K:=K+1;
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        T:=T-1;
        S:=S+2;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The errors are

Error report -
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at line 29
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.

Comment: Check this should help:https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/10/plsql-program-print-patterns.html

Comment: its coming from dbms_output.  It can only hold so much data before it blows up.  You can create a CLOB if you need to

Comment: thanks for the link but i don't really need the code, rather if you could tell me what is the reason for the **errors** generated, i will be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `I` nor `N` are ever updated, so you have an infinite loop.  Other than that, the error is indicating that the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer is being exceeded.  It's default buffer size is 1,000,000 bytes, though you can adjust that with an appropriate DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE call or SET SERVEROUTPUT SIZE statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having has to do with SQL*Plus, the Oracle SQL client, rather than PL/SQL, the programming language. Change the line which says `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` to

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
```

This error *may*, however, indicate you've got an infinite loop, so be careful. Note that `I` never appears to be incremented and `N` is never decremented, so the loop started at `WHILE (I<N) LOOP` may not terminate.

Best of luck.